# Worksheet change event to trigger with Time

Tags: excel, vba, events, time, worksheet

I am looking to run a simple macro to clear contents of cells when time in cell `F4` changes to less than seven minutes (this cell is updated by API). Cell `F4` has time in `hh:mm:ss` format. My code is

```
Sub worksheet_change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = True
Set Target = Range("F4")
If Target.Value <= Minute(7) Then
    Call myClearContents
Application.EnableEvents = False
End If
End Sub
```

This code is in the worksheet and `ClearContents` macro is in a module. I have done the usual google and stackoverflow search, but no luck. Any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a formula in F4? Note - `Minute(7)` doesn't do what you think. And you've got the order of `EnableEvents` off - first `False`, then `True`. And `Set Target` is not what you want - you want to check if `Target` intersects `F4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
' get F3 time
t = CDate(Cells(3, 6))
' get current time
tNow = TimeValue(Now())
' get the difference in minutes
diff = DateDiff("n", t, tNow)

If diff > 7 Then
    Call ClearContents
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. Is there a way to replicate this for 200 sheets. Cell references are exactly the same.